# Message:Command `./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor ./test/protractor.config.js` failed with exit code 1

Tags: google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, protractor, gulp-protractor

I am using gulp with protractor + selenium. The functional tests run on MY machine (mac ) perfectly on Chrome. But on the CENTOS 7(docker container) it doesn't run for Chrome. If I remove the Chromedriver from the PATH variable I get the same error.How do I know if this is a selenium issue or a chromedriver issue? I do an "npm install" and have the "chromedriver": "^2.21.2","protractor": "^3.3.0","selenium-server-standalone-jar": "^2.53.0","webdriver-manager": "^10.0.2" specified in the package.json. What is the issue while running the gulp command?

Here is my error log:

**/home/jenkins/workspace/Myproject/Develop/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:27
super(opt_error);**

**^**

WebDriverError: null
at WebDriverError (/home/jenkins/workspace/Myproject/Develop/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:27:5)
at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/home/jenkins/workspace/Myproject/Develop/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:580:13)
at /home/jenkins/workspace/Myproject/Develop/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:64:13
at Promise.invokeCallback_ (/home/jenkins/workspace/Myproject/Develop/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1329:14)
at TaskQueue.execute_ (/home/jenkins/workspace/Myproject/Develop/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2790:14)
at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/home/jenkins/workspace/Myproject/Develop/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2773:21)
at asyncRun (/home/jenkins/workspace/Myproject/Develop/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2652:27)
at /home/jenkins/workspace/Myproject/Develop/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
at acquireSession (/home/jenkins/workspace/Myproject/Develop/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:62:22)
at Function.createSession (/home/jenkins/workspace/Myproject/Develop/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:295:12) at Builder.build (/home/jenkins/workspace/Myproject/Develop/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:458:24)
at Local.DriverProvider.getNewDriver (/home/jenkins/workspace/Myproject/Develop/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:37:33)
at Runner.createBrowser (/home/jenkins/workspace/Myproject/Develop/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:182:43)
at /home/jenkins/workspace/Myproject/Develop/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:255:30
at _fulfilled (/home/jenkins/workspace/Myproject/Develop/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/jenkins/workspace/Myproject/Develop/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/jenkins/workspace/Myproject/Develop/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
at /home/jenkins/workspace/Myproject/Develop/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44
E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
'test:functional' errored after 25 s
Error in plugin 'gulp-shell'

**Message:
Command  './node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor ./test/protractor.config.js '   failed with exit code 1**

Please help me out

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Comment: @  Marco Aurélio Deleu I fixed it by adding flag `--ignore_ssl=true`to `./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update`